# revoking any or all smart contract permission given

Tags: transactions, metamask, wallets, function, permissions

my question is can I revoke any permissions given to a third party website to acces unlimitted funds from my account.if its possible can someone make a script or guide me into doing it.Cause my funds were drained after 2 days that I allowed it.please i am desperate.I still need something on this account and after that i will make another.thank you in advance dear devs/programmers.I dont knoww what to do.I am trying through python to see if I can revert the acces that I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving any permissions to websites. When you approve that your funds can be used limited or unlimited, you are giving permission to a contract that your funds can only be used in the ways only defined in the contract. However, there are harmful contracts that can funnel your funds to another address.

You can go to https://etherscan.io/tokenapprovalchecker to see which contract you approved for which erc20 token.

You can connect your wallet and then revoke any given approval.

This can solve your problem. But, please note that, if your funds is drained, your case might be different than approval. If somehow they have access to your secret key, no matter if you remove approval they can still access to your funds. I strongly recommend switching to a new address to be sure that you are safe.

Comment: Thank for the reply , but i tried sending monet to pay for the gas fees to revoke and the money dissapears.so i guess it was sweeper bots,so i send etherium on the flashbot rpc network so the bots cannot see the transaccion in the memepool and i revoked it and got acces back to my account,thank god.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: ok , let me refhrase the question.Iy you interact with a malicios contract.Is there a that you can enter in your wallet through python and delete it or rewrite or override the malicious contract call.cause since front end is coded by the back end there should be a way.That was the question.